# How do I track down a synchronization error?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I've recently made my simple graphics library multi-threaded. It is now faster - And the simulation jitters a lot, as if various places had cached old position data and then applied it after it had gone "stale".

Basically, the boxes move, then jerk back, then move, then jerk back...There's no collision as of yet, so it's not that.

Not sure what code to post.

Thanks.

Edit: Whatever it is, also causes lag spikes.

Edit2:

TaskManager:

```
public class TaskManager
{
    public delegate void MethodDel(float timestep);
    private Queue<MethodDel> queue;
    private List<TaskHandler> handlers;
    private float value;


    public float Value
    {
        get
        {
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }


    public TaskManager()
    {
        this.queue = new Queue<MethodDel>();
        this.handlers = new List<TaskHandler>(System.Environment.ProcessorCount);

        for (int t = 0; t < this.handlers.Capacity; ++t)
            this.handlers.Add(new TaskHandler(this));

        foreach (var handler in handlers)
            handler.Start();

        this.value = 0;
    }


    public void Start()
    {
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
            handler.Wake();
    }


    public void Stop()
    {
        lock (queue)
            queue.Clear();

        foreach (var handler in handlers)
            handler.StopWhenDone();
    }


    public void StopWhenDone()
    {
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
            handler.StopWhenDone();
    }


    public void AddToQueue(MethodDel method)
    {
        lock (queue)
            queue.Enqueue(method);
    }


    public bool GetFromQueue(out MethodDel method)
    {
        lock (queue)
        {
            if (queue.Count == 0) { method = null; return false; }

            method = queue.Dequeue();
            return true;
        }
    }


    public int GetQueueCount()
    {
        return queue.Count;
    }

    public void Wait()
    {
        // Have to wait for them one at a time because the main thread is STA.

        WaitHandle[] waitHandles = new WaitHandle[1];
        // for (int t = 0; t < handlers.Count; ++t) waitHandles[t] = handlers[t].WaitHandle;

        // WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles);
        for (int t = 0; t < handlers.Count; ++t) { waitHandles[0] = handlers[t].WaitHandle; WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles); }
    }
}
```

TaskHandler:

```
public class TaskHandler
{
    private TaskManager manager;
    private Thread thread;
    private bool stopWhenDone;
    private ManualResetEvent waitHandle;


    public ManualResetEvent WaitHandle
    {
        get
        {
            return waitHandle;
        }
    }


    public TaskHandler(TaskManager manager)
    {
        this.manager = manager;
    }


    public void Start()
    {
        waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        stopWhenDone = false;

        thread = new Thread(Run);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
        thread.Start();
    }


    public void StopWhenDone()
    {
        this.stopWhenDone = true;
    }


    private void Run()
    {
        TaskManager.MethodDel curMethod;
        while (true)
        {
            while (!stopWhenDone || manager.GetQueueCount() > 0)
            {
                if (manager.GetFromQueue(out curMethod))
                {
                    curMethod(manager.Value);
                }
            }
            waitHandle.Set();
            waitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
    }


    public void Wake()
    {
        waitHandle.Set();
    }
}
```

The main Update loop:

```
    public virtual void Update(float timestep)
    {
        taskManager.Value = timestep; taskManager.Start();

        foreach (Camera camera in cameraLookup.Values)
            // camera.Update(timestep);
            taskManager.AddToQueue(camera.Update);

        taskManager.StopWhenDone();
        taskManager.Wait();

        /* foreach (IAffector affector in affectorLookup.Values)
            affector.Update(timestep); */

        foreach (IAffector affector in affectorLookup.Values)
            taskManager.AddToQueue(affector.Update);

        taskManager.StopWhenDone();
        taskManager.Wait();

        // taskManager.StopWhenDone();
        // taskManager.Wait();

        foreach (IConstraint constraint in constraintLookup.Values)
            // constraint.Update(timestep);
            taskManager.AddToQueue(constraint.Update);

        taskManager.StopWhenDone();
        taskManager.Wait();

        foreach (Physic physic in physicLookup.Values)
            // physic.Update(timestep);
            taskManager.AddToQueue(physic.Update);

        taskManager.StopWhenDone();
        taskManager.Wait();

        foreach (Body body in bodyLookup.Values)
            // body.Update(timestep);
            taskManager.AddToQueue(body.Update);

        taskManager.StopWhenDone();
        taskManager.Wait();

        foreach (Model model in modelLookup.Values)
            // model.Update(timestep);
            taskManager.AddToQueue(model.Update);

        taskManager.StopWhenDone();
        taskManager.Wait();
    }
```

Comment: This is not a question about programming.  It is about cooking spaghetti.  Throw it at the wall, see what sticks.

Comment: without some code it's impossible to answer.  I'd guess your threads are not completing in the order you think they are

Comment: @Hands: Very profound comment. Currently, the Physic.Update is sticking - If I take that out of task threading into single threading, it doesn't jitter, but it does frequently lag sharply.

Comment: @Geoff: I could post my TaskManager and TaskHandler classes, if that might be helpful.

Comment: Thought: I'm using a curState and prevState to store t0 and t-1 physics data. Something could be accessing the wrong state.

Comment: Can you post a simplified version of your Update method? I'm guessing you may have be relying on the order of execution of some operations and you've lost that ordering when you made it multithreaded without realizing it.

Comment: Added. Not sure how it could be executing out-of-order, though. I added the .StopWhenDone() and .Wait() checks to see if it was that.

Comment: I'll be watching one of the position variables soonish; took a break to work on something else to see if my brain would come up with any ideas in the meantime, but it didn't. In the meanwhile, I'll be breaking for the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

How are you managing the data, can you test at the point it is read to tell if it is stale?  Providing advice on a multi-threaded app is pretty difficult.  You could try setting up some tracing and log the specific pieces where you think the problem might be.  If you logged when data is changed and when it is read you might be able to figure out where it is going wrong.

Post some example code to show us how you manage the data and we can take it from there.

Comment: Which data are you referring to? Position data?

Comment: @Narf the Mouse - Yep the position data seems to be the problem so that is where i would start my investigation.

Comment: Well, when it jitters, the model and physic data (or at least, the Y position value of the model and physic CurState I looked at) semi-decouple, but both datasets jitter. Maybe the model is trying to update, but the Physic is locked? Except I don't see how that can happen - It won't "get there from here".

Answer (score 0):

If the data is going "stale", then you need to fix your caching system to evict/update old data.

Threading really isn't that hard, the logic is simple. The problem with threading is identifying your data that is shared and not shared, tracking this data, and make sure this data is updated in the correct order. Most of this has to do with your program's structure. Structure is much much more important when you add threads into your program.

Comment: Thought I answered this - I'm using C#/.Net, so if it is cache problems, it'd be more that I need to make proper use of theirs.